# Replace double number with another in a string

Tags: java, string, substring

If I have multiple strings in the following pattern:

```
String k = "Remain is 2.5"
String k1 = "Remain is 3.5"
String k2 = "Remain is 4.5"
```

How can I replace the double number with another?! It would be a list of strings so number is changed. Also, what's the case if the number's location is changed?!

Example:

```
String k = "Remain 2.5 pounds"
```

Any ideas?!

Comment: is the number always in the end of the String?

Comment: yes but differs each iteration in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that your number is always formatted as a sequence of digits followed by a dot followed by another sequence of digits, and that there is going to be exactly one such sequence per string, you could use `replaceAll` with regex:

```
String res = orig.replaceAll("\\d+[.]\\d+", replacementNumberString);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/nfAP99)

Answer (score 1):

[`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) seems to fit the bill:

```
String k = "Remain is 2.5"
String k1 = k.replace("2.5", "3.5");
String k2 = k.replace("2.5", "4.5");
```

Comment: Yes that's the normal way. My question is the number might not be known so how can it done. It's an array of strings